# Unified Login/Account Wrapper for SQL Server and SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, security, azure, azure-sql-database

I have multiple databases that will exist as an on-premises SQL Server 2012 databases as well as  SQL Azure databases. I understand that some variances exist in the way that logins/roles are handled. Does a "wrapper" of some kind exist, or good rules/patterns for managing security between the two types of SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: Would u please explain more on " some variances exist in the way that logins/roles are handled"? When you have a role with multiple databases, you are going to have multiple connection strings in your role specific web.config, are you looking to secure the connection string or the communication between role and SQL Azure/SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few differences from a security standpoint:

- SQL Azure only supports SQL Server authentication, no integrated auth. So, there's a username/password required.
- SQL Azure does auth checks approx. every 60 minutes, meaning if you change a password, requests may not fail for a while.
- There are a few specific restrictions around creating and dropping databases, logins, and users.

I don't think you need a wrapper. You just need to be cognizant of the subtleties of SQL Azure (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394108#authentication)). As far as connection string differences: you really don't have to do much there, aside from storing multiple connection strings.